# C++ (Arduino) BIN is working, but where is it documented? What is this thing called?

Tags: c++, arduino, binary, format, microcontroller

I coded this (BIN) into my Arduino sketch, and it's working (binary as expected), but I don't see it documented anywhere, so I don't know how to use it better, find others like it, and use it elsewhere. I guess I'd like to know the correct "programmer-speak", so I can do more research into other available options in similar scenarios:

`randBinary = random(BIN);`

I hacked the above into my code after seeing the following on official documentation (use of BIN):

`Serial.print(78, BIN) gives "1001110"`

from: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/

Comment: did you check the meaning of the parameter in `random`? https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/

Comment: guess what is the value of the macro BIN https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/blob/master/api/Print.h#L30

Comment: @Juraj Yes, which is why it's baffling to me (not binary):  
"The max parameter should be chosen according to the data type of the variable in which the value is stored. In any case, the absolute maximum is bound to the long nature of the value generated (32 bit - 2,147,483,647). Setting max to a higher value won’t generate an error during compilation, but during sketch execution the numbers generated will not be as expected."

Comment: @Juraj I know you just answered one of my questions. It's called a "macro". I didn't know that. Thanks. I see how it's in the code for Arduino, but I find it odd that it's not actually documented elsewhere. Seems they can be used anywhere with some limits, just as I did.

Comment: the parameter of random is not for the type. it is for the required range. if you want to choose a random day of week you will use `random(7)` or `random (1, 8)`. to simulate a dice roll you will use `random(1, 7)`

Comment: @Juraj But I do wish some function to randomize a binary. This is working (serial console confirms), but like I said, I don't know more about it, other than it's working. I'd like to know the rules and where they are written.

Comment: what rules? random(2) can return only 0 or 1. you should not use BIN here. BIN is for `print`

Comment: @Juraj I think you just helped me understand what this means on the Arduino reference of random() "A random number between min and max-1. Data type: long." OK I'll try that in place... YES, I confirm it works the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIN is a preprocessor macro defined as `#define BIN 2`. It is defined in [Print.h](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/blob/master/api/Print.h#L30) to use as second parameter of `print` functions where the first parameter is of integer numeric type. The second parameter specifies the base in which the number should be printed. Default is decimal (DEC) of course. Other common number base formats used in computers are binary, hexadecimal and octal, so Print.h has preprocessor macros for 10, 2, 16 and 8 called DEC, BIN, HEX and OCT. The print function can be used with other base formats using a number as the second parameter. (Note. The second parameter in print function with first parameter as float or double is count of decimal places to print.)

The function [random](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/) in Arduino has 2 overloaded versions. A version with one parameter `max` and a version with two parameters `min' and` max'.

The parameters of random specify the required range. For example if you want to choose a random day of week you will use `random(7)` or `random (1, 8)`. Other example is if you want to simulate a dice roll you will use `random(1, 7)`.

You should not use BIN as parameter for`random`. It will work because BIN is 2, but it is not the intended use of the macro BIN.

Comment: I'm about to accept your answer, but before I do, just for further clarification as with my first question, other preprocessor macros are documented where? Previously you gave the GitHub link: github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/blob/master/api/Print.h#L30 but I wonder if there's other documentation, or where I might find more of these in code. I understand now how it should not be used outside of its intention as with anything via Print.h such as print() and println().

Comment: @bento the 'Arduino language; documentation doesn't go to C++ details. for beginners it is better to show example usage than list all possible parameters of overloaded functions. experienced users look into the source files. the header files show what is available. the source files are on your computer to be compiled with your sketch or you can view them  in source code repositories like GitHub